# How to solve unicode display wrong (different) characters issue in ubuntu?

Tags: fonts, unicode, unicode-entry

I'm struggling to display Unicode (Nepali) character in right form. While typing Nepali Unicode or translating in Nepali language from translate.google.com in Ubuntu OS it displays wrong (different) characters but the same process shows the right characters in Windows and Android OS.

Unicode character display in Windows:

[image: Unicode Character Display In windows OS]

Unicode character display in Ubuntu:

[image: Unicode Character Display In Ubuntu OS]

Comment: I don't know Nepali, but those characters look the same for me. Different font, but the same characters. Also, online results from google can differ per client, so getting a result on one machine does not imply that another machine will get exactly the same. It would be better to save that as text document somewhere or visit a site with fixed text. And have you already tried to change the display font? Ubuntu does not use the same fonts as Windows.

Comment: @ByteCommander, no, there are huge differences. The leftmost character looks like a backwards 'K' in Windows and a backwards 'h' in Ubuntu. The second leftmost character in Ubuntu is **completely missing** on Windows. Somehow Ubuntu inserted a nonexistent character before the character that looks like a backwards '3'!

Comment: Okay, but still: make sure you're getting the exactly same text. Google services are not a good choice because their results can differ from client to client and from query to query.

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `locale -a`. I am wondering if you have added Nepali language in system settings

Comment: Hello everyone warm greeting,  this is output (display) problem in web browser of Ubuntu (All browser) and issue is grammatical issue.  In windows browser (All browser) give the right output whereas Ubuntu didn't. I think the issue is in Devanagari script in Ubuntu. I found this problem in Nepali, Hindi and Sanskrit. The Devanagari script is used for over 120 languages, including Sanskrit, Nepali, Hindi, Marathi, Pali, Konkani, Bodo, Sindhi and Maithili. I am looking for solution to show the Unicode output like windows browser in Ubuntu (All browser). Is there any solution? Guide me please.

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for solution to this problem and I eventually fixed it using

```
apt-get install language-pack-ne language-pack-ne-base mythes-ne ttf-devanagari-fonts libreoffice-l10n-ne
```

Sharing here: https://aabhash.com.np/fix-nepali-devnagari-texts-display-problem-on-ubuntu/